# Why does cricket ball swing more on overcast days than on sunny days

Tags: everyday-life, aerodynamics

**Why does the cricket ball swing more on cloudy overcast days than on sunny days?**

There have been research papers investigating the reasons for cricket ball swing, and they have provided evidence ruling out the role of humidity as the causal factor for more swing on overcast conditions.
The paper attempted to replicate the effect by changing humidity and was not able to do it.

To support my point, I am quoting the papers in question: Mehta, R. D. (2005). *An overview of cricket ball swing*. Sports Engineering, 8(4), 181–192 (emphasis mine)

> *The question of the effect of humidity on cricket ball swing is still not totally resolved. While the effect is often **observed on the cricket ground**, there is not enough laboratory
> evidence to explain how the amount of swing may be increased in humid conditions.*

James, D., MacDonald, D. C., & Hart, J. (2012). *The effect of atmospheric conditions on the swing of a cricket ball*. Procedia Engineering, 34, 188–193. (emphasis mine)

> [...] *despite laudable attempts in numerous studies, there is currently no experimentally validated theory that has been able to reveal the mechanisms that cause the effect.*
>
> [...] ***Lyttleton observed that** the best conditions for swing were humid sultry days*
>
> [...] *cloud cover is the atmospheric condition of primary concern, not humidity
> t**he ball swings more on cloudy, overcast days** and whilst the humidity levels on these days may tend to be higher than normal, humidity is not the key factor.*"

To the comments claiming that the papers say, this effect is not real, i would reiterate that, they concluded that humidity is not the reason for ball swinging more on overcast days. They did **not** conclude that the effect of ball swinging more on overcast days is not real. This is a real effect visible on video recordings of cricket matches *and* is also recorded on the ball tracking data that is collected for each match.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128705/discussion-on-question-by-silverrahul-follow-up-to-why-does-cricket-ball-swing).

Comment: @AlBrown The differential roughness on both sides (achieved by polishing one side of the ball throughout the game ) creates lateral force by making airflow on only one side of the ball turbulent, while airflow on the other side stays laminar. This only works, if the air is laminar to begin with . If the air is already turbulent to begin with, then the required condition of laminar on one side and turbulent on the other side cannot be achieved.

Comment: You dont need laminar and turbulent to get a net force. You only need one side more rough than the other. Laminar and turbulent on the same object pretty much never happens.

Comment: @AlBrown One side being more rough than other, creates force BY creating turbulent airflow on rough side and letting it stay laminar on polished side. How else do you think, one side being more rough than other creates swing ? " _Laminar and turbulent on the same object pretty much never happens_ "  Watch the wind tunnel video linked by physics_newb to see the laminar flow and turbulent flow on the 2 sides of the same ball.

Comment: Wow youre right. Im very surprised. I thought we were an order of magnitude past laminar. I guess laminar boundary layers exist far into the overall “turbulent flow regime”

Comment: Yeah i was definitely wrong. But it’s not true that you *need* different flow regimes to have curvature. Normally thats not the cause of balls curving. You can have different drag on a rough side vs smooth side, even when both sides are on the same flow regime. And also of course spins creating different flow rates over the surface - the most common cause. But i see here

Comment: @AlBrown " _But it’s not true that you need different flow regimes to have curvature. Normally thats not the cause of balls curving._ "
Different kinds of balls have different exact mechanisms. A football free kick,, a curveball in  baseball and a swinging cricket ball do not necessarily experience deviation through the exact same mechanism. For cricket ball swing, specifically, the difference in flow regimes on the 2 sides are an important reason for why it swings.

Comment: Agree w all that. Sounds great man.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Why the cricket ball swings

To understand why the cricket ball swings more in overcast conditions, you have  to first understand  why the cricket ball swings in the first place.

The cricket ball swings when the ball travels through laminar air and the effect of the raised seam of the ball combined with the differential surface roughness of the 2 halves of the ball (one side is polished by the players throughout the game) causes the air on one side of the ball to become turbulent.
This difference of airflow on the 2 sides of the ball, laminar on one side and turbulent on the other side causes the ball to swing.

So, to achieve swing, you need non-turbulent air, so that the ball can then cause air on only one side of it to become turbulent leading to lateral force on the ball.

### Why the ball swings more under clouds and less when it's sunny

One thing that stops the ball from swinging is a lack of non-turbulent air. If the air is sufficiently disturbed already, before the ball passes through it, then there is no chance of the necessary laminar  flow over one side of the ball that is needed to create swing.

One thing that we know creates this type of micro-turbulence is the action of the sun heating the pitch. On a sunny day, the sun’s rays heat the pitch, which in turn warms the layer of air next to it. Because hot air rises, this warm air then bubbles up through the colder air above it, creating a block of micro-turbulence – little swirls, eddies and currents in the air – above the pitch. This air is not tranquil enough to allow laminar flow over an object moving through it. So , the ball will have turbulent flow around both sides, and won’t swing.

How do we know this micro-turbulence exists above cricket pitches?
Well, because we can see it. If you have ever seen a heat haze rising off the road on a hot day, then you have seen the sort of micro-turbulence that we are talking about. And photos across a cricket pitch show the same type of heat haze rising off the ground. Once that turbulence is there, you can’t get laminar flow, and without laminar flow, the ball can’t swing.

This is why you see the ball swinging more during cloud cover, as well as during  twilight and during the first session early in the morning, when it is damp. These are the types of conditions that encourage swing. Because they prevent the sun from heating the pitch and destroying the laminar flow necessary for swing.

This would also explain why this effect could not be replicated in the lab by just changing the humidity, as that does not replicate the effect of the sun disrupting the laminar flow near the pitch surface.

Comment: That’s interesting and could be the main factor. Except it’s not laminar flow, just lower roughness.

Comment: @AlBrown The laminar flow is instrumental part of what happens. Check out this video where Matt Kari of Sheffield university who did wind tunnel tests of cricket ball aerodynamics talks about " _because this side is smooth, the airflow around this side is laminar flow_ "   https://youtu.be/W4tGaoSz14g?t=53

Comment: Wow youre right. Im very surprised. I thought we were an order of magnitude past laminar. I guess laminar boundary layers exist far into the overall “turbulent flow regime”.

Answer (score -1):

In baseball, it is generally know that the roughness of the surface is primary. This is also true in aerodynamics where “relative roughness” is a key parameter in determining aerodynamic pipe losses, or drag. So anything that would affect the roughness would be an immediate suspected culprit. Pitchers are caught with files and/or sand paper making the ball rougher.

It should be emphasized. Relative roughness is more important than reynolds number in the Moody chart. For something spinning in a medium, roughness becomes even more important comparatively. There are no other dynamics to help set-up viscous sheer under rotation. Something very smooth can spin with minor resistance. Also, the smoother the ball is, the tinier can be the changes to its surface such that those changes matter.  And unlike a baseball, a cricket ball only has one raised equator; this means that there is only one axis of rotation with orthogonal cutting by a seam. A baseball cannot be forced by wind resistance into a rotation where seams are parallel to the direction of rotation. I predict this quickly happens to a cricket ball in flight, largely because axial airflow pushes on the seam only on the leading side. (For example, if the ball is rotating about an angle 45 degrees from flight path and on the leading side of the ball the seam is on the right.. then the axial flow only hits the seam on the right (when the seam is in the front) and can quickly bend the axis of rotation until it’s parallel to direction of travel.)

So the surface of the ball matters. But the seams matter more. Anything that deepens or roughens the seam a little will increase curving, because, as just described, it ends up on the spinning equator oriented to have maximum tangential speed.

If the cricket ball is painted, and the coefficient of thermal expansion of the paint is higher than that of the ball, this would matter for two reasons on sunny days:

1. With differential thermal expansion, heating the entire object would make the part with higher coefficient grow more. In the case of paint (or other composite construction that varies material radially), ridges or small grooves, even invisible one, would affect flight curvature under spin
2. Sun might heat the outside of the ball more than high air temperature would. The ball gives heat to its environment via convection and radiation, and radiation out is relatively low.

Dew point and condensation could also matter. Baseball pitchers always want the ball to be wet (the notorious “spitball” exemplifies). One can dry a ball but not necessarily wet it. If the grass is wet (**which happens most on overcast days even much more so than on humid days**), that might be the whole cause.

If very dry grass is present, it is constantly drying the ball and seam, and doing a sort of polishing of the seam. So the question might not be about how humid the air is but about how “humid” the grass is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128765/discussion-on-answer-by-al-brown-follow-up-to-why-does-cricket-ball-swing-more).